How to install packages or libraries in VS Code User Installer/environment
I am using VS Code User Installer on my work laptop. This means everything is installed at the user level. Next, I followed the steps mentioned on the R Extension for Visual Studio Code to install support for R language.

Install R (>= 3.4.0) on your system.
install.packages("languageserver")
Install the R extension for VS Code from the VS Code Extension Marketplace
Create an R file and start coding.

Following step 2, when I tried to install "languageserver", it failed, giving me the following error messages.
> install.packages("languageserver")
Installing package into 'C:/Users/1229437/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://cran.wu.ac.at/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/languageserver_0.3.16.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 826432 bytes (807 KB)
downloaded 807 KB

package 'languageserver' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package 'languageserver'
Warning: restored 'languageserver'

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\1229437\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOiMn77\downloaded_packages
Warning message:
In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\1229437\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\00LOCK\languageserver\libs\x64\languageserver.dll
  to C:\Users\1229437\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\languageserver\libs\x64\languageserver.dll: Permission denied

It looks like the problem is with copying the required files to the R library folder. Maybe it is because I am logged in as a User on my work laptop and don't have the proper permissions. What is the best way to get rid of this error other than buying and using a personal laptop :-)

Sounds like something your system's administrator should be bothered with. :)
What are that folder permissions? Can you manually remove and of the files in that folder?

It seems that the issue was with VS Code itself. Whenever I tried to install certain packages using the R terminal within VS Code, I received a "permission denied" error. However, when I closed VS Code and used the R terminal that was installed with the language installer, the package installation was successful. After reopening VS Code, everything worked perfectly.
